# Giving link href to swiper slide

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, swiper.js

hi ı made a slider wit swiper.js and ı edited it but ı have problem this website gonna be a news site so that in slider there is gonna be lots of news and when ı clicked it it must to direct
me to a news detail page

i tried to give a "a" and href but it didn't work ı searched in google but there no answer can you help me there is the code example

```
      <swiper-container class="mySwiper swiperIndex" init="false">
              <swiper-slide>
                <a href="example.com">
                <div class="information-slide d-flex flex-column">
                  <div class="important-information z-3">
                    <span class="bgColor w-auto p-2 text-white"
                      >Important Title Part</span
                    >
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <h1 class="text-white mt-3">Example Title Name</h1>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <img
                  src="https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/351/800/500.jpg?hmac=z6hCcK3YLnV3WXE85n1jHXmX2_hlzoXFWFZeyf2NWcg"
                  alt=""
                />
                <div class="swiper-bg-fix"></div>
                </a>

              </swiper-slide>
</swiper-container>
```

Comment: See this post. Maybe this will solve it:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29367023/how-to-make-swiper-js-images-clickable